# how to change the status in database with clicking on a button

Tags: jquery, sql, laravel

i'am working in laravel project , so i want to change the status of patient when he take an appointement with doctor , so he can have 3 satuts , Accept , waiting , not accept , i'am asking how can i change the satatus with only clicking on button and thank you .

This is controller witch the doctor edit an appointement  :

```
  public function edit ($id) {

        $rdv= rendezvous::find($id);
        return view ('/edit', ['modifier'=>$rdv]); }
```

this is the view witch the doctor can see his patients and edit or accept or reject an appointement

```
      <h3> the patients :</h3>
                    @foreach($patient as $pat)
                    @if ($pat->IDD== $doctor->ID)
                    <div class="admin">

                      <div class="info">
                        <h3> {{ $pat->Name_Last_Name    }} </h3>
                        <p>{{ $pat->phone_number }}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{url('edit/'.$pat->id) }}" > edit </a>
                    @endif

    @endforeach
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on which button you wanna click so it can change status? Is it edit button?

Comment: @AbhishekHonrao no is not edit , new button witch have Accept value

Comment: Hmm, are you sure `{{url('edit/'.$pat->id) }}` is a correct way to insert variables?

Comment: yes it's work THE EDIT @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your clarification.

Let's consider, once you got appointment, then status will be `not-accepted` automatically. Once you click on `chanage status` btn then it will change to `waiting` and at last `accepted`.

In your blade -

```
<a onclick="status({{$pat->id}})" class="btn">Change Status</a>
```

In js -

```
function status(id) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/update-status',
      data: {
        'id': id
      },
      success: function(data){
           //redirect where you want..
      },
    });
};
```

In your controller -

```
public function status(Request $request){
 $id = $request->id;

 $status = rendezvous::where('id', $id)->value('status');

 if($status === 'not-accepted'){
  $status = 'waiting';
 } elseif($status === 'waiting'){
  $status = 'accepted';
}
rendezvous::where('id', $id)->update(['status'=> $status]);

return response()->json('success');
}
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but sorry this not work with me :(

Comment: when i click on the button , the status still the same

Comment: Ok. Go ahead and debug your code. Go to controller and check what id are you getting and check wahts the status are you getting from query. Go step by step. As example, check ```dd($id)```. This will give you a value and let me know.